# Declare function inside the body tag leads to "Function not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I render a java script function inside the body tag of my html. After the java script there is a button which calls this function which is declared by the `onclick` attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function f(caller){
        console.log('test');
    }
</script>
<button onclick="f(this)" type="button">A button</button>
```

The problem is that it says "ReferenceError: f is not defined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dKCpU/ It works just fine.

Comment: Put the script after the button.

Comment: lol "F this" - was that example deliberate? @jakup - your fiddle cant run cause it wont let js in the html body. not the same as OP's claim

Comment: @kai it let's you put the script into body, it just pops and alert that you shouldn't, see: http://jsfiddle.net/p28zK/ has the same result

Comment: Before and After ... Both are working  Before : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/123/ After : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/124/

Comment: @jakub - huzzah! indeed it does. I was also just looking for an excuse to laugh at f(this)

Comment: There must be something else, this was supposed to work. Do you happen to have your function wrapped on another function? Maybe a document.ready (or onload, etc), or an IIFE?

Comment: mh, thats very strange. why am I getting an error in my code?

Comment: Is that button the only place where you call `f`? Please show us your whole page, as it stands everything you posted works.

Comment: the whole page is 2500 lines of html code ;-) I think I found a potential problem: Is it a problem if I declare the function more than one time? So the <script> part repeats with the function inside it. Is that the problem?

Comment: @tester: As a general recommendation, instead of dealing with those sort of issue where scripts are littered throughout, add your script for the page into a single `.js` file and reference it inside the  `head` tag or add the script directly into a single `script` tag inside the `head`. Using `window.onload()`, `addEventListener()`, `getElementById`, `querySelectorAll()` and `document.querySelector()` should be more than enough to do all the event binding and function declarations in a single manageable place. It will also keep your HTML very clean and the script easier to manage and oversee.

Comment: the problem is I have to render a URL into this javascript. I can only render it inside a remplate file. I can't render it into the head tag because it is another template file. So I can't use a external js file.

Comment: @tester: Fair enough. I suppose your project may be to far in, but as a general note; you can add the url into a hidden field and access the value from script and assign it to any other element, use it as a variable for an ajax call or redirect. There is many ways of doing it and still be able to keep you HTML clean. If you referring to templating as in backbone or knockoutjs they all allow for flexibility as well. Nothing should ever force you having to write in-line script or use external js files. That would be very bad design.

Comment: Thats the solution. render url into hidden field. thx!

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work just fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function f(caller){
            console.log('test');
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <button onclick="f(this)" type="button">A button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are receiving that error, it is probably from somewhere else other than the code you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the right location for the script within the `body` tag I would recommend to use the [**window.onload**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload), function as well as binding the event yourself using [**addEventListener()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk%3aDOM/element.addEventListener) inside the `script` tags within the `head` tags were it should be or even in an external `.js` file.

Give your button an `id` if you want to use [**getElementById()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) to select it, similar to this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var f = function(caller) {
        console.log('test');
    };

    var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
    myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        f(this);
    });
};
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xrm9P/) - Using `window.onload()` and `addEventListener()`

---

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was that I wrote

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="........." />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function f(caller){
        console.log('test');
    }
</script>
```

but it should be with a `</script>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="........." ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function f(caller){
        console.log('test');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you should explain the difference